# How to disable return key of the keyboard on condition in swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard

I have three textfields one for company name second for email and third one is for password. I want to enable return button only if all the three fields are filled. Is it feasible in swift?

Comment: nope...........

Answer (score -2):

Check the number of strings in the text field to make sure it was entered.
After confirming the input in the three text fields.
and... Button active.

Comment: no bro it's not working